# How to add Emails as Editors of whole document using a Setup Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to take my project from a stage to another, and I was able to make some good progress so far.

I've got the following script that runs when the sheet called Setup_Protections is edited: it removes all the sheets protections then add them back with the Emails specified in the Setup sheet (i.e. add those emails as editors of the protected sheets).

But the problem is that the spreadsheet needs to be shared beforehand so they can access it first. Is there a way to share in the same time the document with the emails entered in the Setup sheet ? (without necessary using a method that requires enabling Sheets API as I'll be duplicating many times the documents)

Thank you for your help

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/199wstlB1u8hFUkl1WcnoPb8tlsrNZGN7V5oBgZWTH9Y)

**MY SCRIPT:`**

```
var environment = {
protectionConfigSheetName: "Setup_Protection",
};

// Script fires when Setup_Protection is edited

function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === environment.protectionConfigSheetName) 
resetSpreadsheetProtections();
}



function removeSpreadsheetProtections(spreadsheet) {
[
    SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET,

].forEach(function (type) {
    return spreadsheet.getProtections(type).forEach(function (protection) { return protection.remove(); });
});
}

function getProtectionConfig(spreadsheet) {

  var protectionConfigSheetName = "Setup_Protection";
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(environment.protectionConfigSheetName); 

  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var protectionConfig = values
      .slice(1)
      .reduce(function (protectionConfig, _a) {
      var targetSheetName = _a[0], emailAddress = _a[1];
      var config = protectionConfig.find(function (_a) {
          var sheetName = _a.sheetName;
          return sheetName === targetSheetName;
      });
      var editors = emailAddress.split(",");
      if (config)
          config.editors = config.editors.concat(editors);
      else
          protectionConfig.push({
              sheetName: targetSheetName,
              editors: editors.slice()
          });
      return protectionConfig;
  }, []);
  return protectionConfig;
 }


function setSpreadsheetProtections(spreadsheet, protectionConfig) {
spreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(function (sheet) {
    var protection = sheet.protect();
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors().map(function(editor) {
        return editor.getEmail();
    }));
    var currentSheetName = sheet.getName();
    var config = protectionConfig.find(function (_a) {
        var sheetName = _a.sheetName;
        return sheetName === currentSheetName;
    });
    if (config)
        protection.addEditors(config.editors);
});
}



 function resetSpreadsheetProtections() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var protectionConfig = getProtectionConfig(spreadsheet);
 removeSpreadsheetProtections(spreadsheet);
setSpreadsheetProtections(spreadsheet, protectionConfig);
 }
```

Note: there is also another script needed for this one called Polyfill.gs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's working now:

Add the following to the above code:

```
function addEditorsToSpreadsheetFromProtectionConfig(spreadsheet, protectionConfig) {
var editors = protectionConfig.reduce(function (accumulator, _a) {
var editors = _a.editors;
return accumulator.concat(editors);
}, []);

spreadsheet.addEditors(editors);
}
```

Then Add to `resetSpreadsheetProtections()` the following line:

```
  addEditorsToSpreadsheetFromProtectionConfig(spreadsheet, protectionConfig);
```